# I need help on rewrite rules for my wordpress blog in sub folder

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a main domain with static html files suppose, https://example.com which is in the folder 'example' in my server root directory. So to point the domain inside 'example' folder, I added following rewrite rules in root .htaccess file.

```
# Do not change this line.
RewriteEngine on
  
# Change yourdomain.com to be your main domain.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
  
# Change 'subfolder' to be the folder you will use for your main domain.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/example/
  
# Don't change this line.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  
# Change 'subfolder' to be the folder you will use for your main domain.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /example/$1
  
# Change yourdomain.com to be your main domain again.
# Change 'subfolder' to be the folder you will use for your main domain
# followed by / then the main file for your site, index.php, index.html, etc.
  
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ example/index.html [L]
```

This works perfectly for my main domain single page site. Now I want to add wordpress blog inside this domain as https://example.com/blog
So I installed wordpress inside 'example' folder as root/example/blog

Now the problem is when I enter https://example.com/blog, it shows not found error but is accessible as https://example.com/example/blog.

How can I make the blog work as https://example.com/blog?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It seems your redirects are configured correctly.

I believe the problem lies with WordPress.

It expects your blog to be hosted at /example/blog/ and works with that path. If you try to access it using the redirect WordPress only sees the original path /blog/ and does not recognize it as a valid path and gives a 404 response. Change the paths in WP and you should be good.